# RSpec Argument Error invalid keys :method, :action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Is anyone able to shed light on why this error:

```
 Failure/Error:
   expect(render).to have_selector('form', method: 'post', action: 'index') do |form|
     expect(form).to have_selector('input', type: 'submit')

 ArgumentError:
   invalid keys :method, :action, should be one of :count, :minimum, :maximum, :between, :text, :visible, :exact, :match, :wait
```

is generated on this code:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe "messages/new.html.erb" do
  it "renders a form to create a message" do
    assign(:message, mock_model('Message'))
    render
    expect(render).to have_selector('form',
      method: 'post',
      action: 'index'
    ) do |form|
      expect(form).to have_selector('input', type: 'submit')
    end
  end
end
```

Much thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your call to `have_selector` isn't right: you can't check for the presence of attributes on elements in that way. You can however include this in the selector, eg

```
have_selector("form[method=post][action=index]")
```

If the rendered html actually has the full path or url for the form then you need to use the routing helpers to generate that url and use it in the selector.